# How do I fix IE absolute positioning CSS rendering error triggered by overall stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am experiencing an error where Internet Explorer (11, Edge mode) should display this:

[image: Correct placement]

But instead displays this (note the botton on the right):

[image: Wrong placement]

The error has been triggered due to a *recent (unknown) change in the overall stylesheet for this* page: **http://www.science.ku.dk/uddannelser/studenterservice/studenterservice_kopi/**. This style.css is outside my control and is located at **http://cms.ku.dk/styling/css/style.css**.

I am not able to reproduce this error outside this website.

Interestingly, **Internet Explorer renders the wrongly placed element correctly when clicking the element, and/or when disabling and re-enabling the "div.wrapsklabel { bottom: 0; }" from the stylesheet.**

The page is rendered correcly in this version at **https://blanketter.science.ku.dk/studenterservice/test.html** which doesn't use the overall stylesheet.

My own code is pretty simple and, I think, pretty much correct, so right now I am trying to find out **what part of style.css could possibly be triggering the rendering error I am experiencing?** and **what can I change in my own CSS to fix this?**

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

**CSS**

```
div.stederss {
    display:table;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing: 15px;
}


div.stederss div.column1ss,
div.stederss div.column2ss {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    display:table-cell;
    *display:block;
    *float:left;
    *height:401px;
    *margin: 15px 0px 15px; 0;
    width:50%;
    *width:349px;
    padding:0px;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:1.5em;
    position:relative;
}

div.stederss div.column1ss {
    border: 1px solid #97ad7c;
    *margin-right: 15px;
}

div.stederss div.column2ss {
    border: 1px solid #8AB7B4;
}

div.wrapsklabel {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%; 
}

div.overskrifthd {
    font-family: Noto Sans, Verdana;
    background-color: #97ad7c;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 17px 10px 17px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11pt;
}

div.overskriftsk {
    font-family: Noto Sans, Verdana;
    background-color: #8AB7B4;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 17px 10px 17px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11pt;
}

div.deklaration {
    padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}   

.stederss input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -5000px;
}


label.helpdesklabel {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    display:block;
    font-family: Noto Sans, Verdana;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    color: #165aad;
    padding: 17px 10px 17px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10pt;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

label.ssklabel {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    display:block;
    font-family: Noto Sans, Verdana;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    color: #165aad;
    padding: 17px 10px 17px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10pt;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="stederss">
    <div class="column1ss">
        <div class="overskrifthd">HELP DESK
        </div>

        <div class="deklaration">
            <strong>Få svar på praktiske og administrative spørgsmål om din uddannelse.</strong><ul><li>Spørgsmål om kursus- og eksamenstilmelding</li><li>Få bekræftet din studieaktivitet og dine indskrivningsforhold, fx til boligselskaber</li><li>Få rettet fejl i tilmeldinger eller registreringer</li><li>Lav navne- og adresseændring</li><li>Få karakterudskrifter</li><li>Få bekræftet kopi af dit eksamensbevis</li><li>Få rettet fejl i dit eksamensbevis</li><li>Udmeld dig af din uddannelse</li><li>Få registreret dit rigtige CPR-nummer</li></ul>
        </div>

        <div class="wraphelpdesksmall">
            <input id="2" type="radio" value="hd" name="sted">
            <label class="helpdesklabel" for="2">Klik for at kontakte<br> Help Desk</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column2ss">

        <div class="overskriftsk">Studie- og karrierevejledningen
        </div>

        <div class="deklaration">
            <strong>Få vejledning i indhold, opbygning og regler for din uddannelse og få de bedste forudsætninger for et godt studieforløb.</strong><ul><li>Planlæg dit studieforløb og din tid</li><li>Træf velovervejede valg</li><li>Fasthold din motivation og håndter tvivl undervejs</li><li>Få sparring på dine karriereovervejelser</li><li>Kom af sted på udlandsophold</li><li>Få vejledning om ansøgninger, frister, dispensationer og klager</li><li>Håndter det svære, fx dumpede eksamener, sygdom og stress</li></ul>
        </div>

        <div class="wrapsklabel">
            <input class="sskknappen" type="radio" name="sted" value="ssk" id="1">
            <label class="ssklabel" for="1">Klik for at kontakte<br> Studie- og karrierevejledningen</label>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I have created a fidlle with the code at **https://jsfiddle.net/hxgqrLa9/** but as the error is not reproduced without the external stylesheet, I doubt it is of much help.

Thank you for any help you could possibly provide.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try a couple of things like below:

1. Avoid using ".stederss input[type="radio"] {" in the css, instead use an alternate way like using a class like ".stederss .radio {" and use the class="radio" wherever you are having type="radio"...
2. Try to check is the path is accessible while using the eternal css.

Let me know if that works.